# Вставляю часть кода в код основной программы, и он перестает работать

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть рабочий код, он создает 2 файла и наполняет их тем, что пишет пользователь:

```
userf = input('Введите название рецепта: ')
txting = (str(userf) + ' Ингридиенты' )
fING = (str(txting) + '.txt')
fing = open(fING, 'x', encoding='utf-8')

while True:
    print('Введите "x" если не хотите добавлять ингридиент')
    Ing = input('Введите ингридиент: ')
    if Ing == 'x':
        break
    else:
        fing.write(Ing)
        fing.write('\n')
        fing.write('\n')

txtcook = (str(userf) + ' Порядок приготовления' )
fCOOK = (str(txtcook) + '.txt')
fcook = open(fCOOK, 'x', encoding='utf-8')

while True:
    print('\nВведите "x" если не хотите добавлять пункт порядка приготовления')
    Cook = input('пункт порядка приготовления: ')
    if Cook == 'x':
        break
    else:
        fcook.write(Cook)
        fcook.write('\n')
        fcook.write('\n')
```

Но когда я вставляю его в основной код, он создает файлы, но ничего в них не записывает (python ошибок не выдает)

Вот основной код:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style # Импорт колорамы (для цветного текста в консоль)
from colorama import init              # Импорт колорамы (для цветного текста в консоль)
init()                                 # Импорт колорамы (для цветного текста в консоль)


print(Back.GREEN) # Зеленый текст
print ('Добро пожаловать в программу "Recipes"')

print(Back.RED) # Красный текст
print('Введите "x" чтобы выйти')

print(Back.YELLOW) # Желтый текст
print ('Введите "+" чтобы добавить новый рецепт')

print(Back.YELLOW) # Желтый текст
print ('Введите "ls" чтобы просмотреть список рецептов')

what = input ('') # Поле для ввода команды

while True: 
    if what == 'x': # Команда для закрытия программы 
        break # Закрытие програмы

    elif what == '+': # Команда для создания файла с рецептом
        userf = input('Введите название рецепта: ')
        txting = (str(userf) + ' Ингридиенты' )
        fING = (str(txting) + '.txt')
        fing = open(fING, 'x', encoding='utf-8')

        while True:
            print(Back.RED)
            print('Введите "x" если не хотите добавлять ингридиент')
            print(Back.GREEN)
            Ing = input('Введите ингридиент: ')
            if Ing == 'x':
                break
            else:
                fing.write(Ing)
                fing.write('\n')
                fing.write('\n')

        txtcook = (str(userf) + ' Порядок приготовления' )
        fCOOK = (str(txtcook) + '.txt')
        fcook = open(fCOOK, 'x', encoding='utf-8')

        while True:
            print(Back.RED)
            print('\nВведите "x" если не хотите добавлять пункт порядка приготовления')
            print(Back.GREEN)
            Cook = input('пункт порядка приготовления: ')
            if Cook == 'x':
                break
            else:
                fcook.write(Cook)
                fcook.write('\n')
                fcook.write('\n')

    elif what == 'ls':
        pass

    else:
        print ('Ошибка. Введена неверная комманда')
```

Comment: Проверил ваш код, он работает. Создает файлы, всё записывает. Единственное, у вас нет выхода из режима добавления рецептов.

Comment: Странно... Я новичок и пока не знаю как сделать выход((